# Getting a range error on fetching data from firebase after restarting my app

Tags: flutter, dart

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

When I restart my app and try to fetch data from existing collection on firebase, I get this range error even though I have included itemcount in ListView and also checking if data is present. It works perfectly fine and shows data if I am adding data in a new instance of the app without any previous data.
How to fix this?

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("ToDo").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshots){

            if(snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshots.hasData)
            {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } 
            else 
            {
              return Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
              DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot= snapshots.data.documents[index];
              //return a widget
```

Comment: Can you post the error with its full stacktrace? Also `snapshots.data == ConnectionState.waiting` should be `snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting`.

Comment: @enzo Thank you, I have corrected my mistake and fixed the error somehow.